# GetType().Name from Class with generic Type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way, without doing some Stringoperations, to get the Typename without the count of generic type arguments?

In my Example below I need ***CreatedEvent*** instead of ***CreatedEvent`1***?

```
public class LogEvent<T> {

    public LogEvent (T logObj) {
        LogObject = logObj;
    }

    T LogObject { get; private set; }

    public string GetEventName () {
        return GetType().Name;
    }
}

public class CreatedEvent<T> : LogEvent<T> {
    public CreatedEvent(T logObj) : base (logObj) {} 
}

public class DeleteEvent : LogEvent<SomeObj> {
    public DeleteEvent(SomeObj logObj) : base (logObj) {}
}

// --
var created = new CreatedEvent<SomeObj>( exampleObj );
var deleted = new DeleteEvent( exampleObj );

// --

Console.WriteLine ( created.GetEventName() ); // CreatedEvent`1
Console.WriteLine ( deleted.GetEventName() ); // DeletedEvent
```

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't such way. Why do you want to avoid string operations?

Comment: Why do you *need* this? It's part of the name. It isn't really different from wanting to e.g. get `MouseEventArgs` without that pesky `EventArgs` suffix - and the solution is exactly the same, really :)